# Savefig takes forever

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, canopy

I wanted to use `savefig` command of `matplotlib`. While creating the image takes 2.578 seconds only, when the `g.show()` is replaced with `g.savefig("path\\"+"fig.pdf")`, the time it takes increases to 391.946 seconds.

The same time delay occurs when I use `g.show()`  and then try to save it from the shown image file.

I am using python for several years now and it was never this slow. What can be the reason for this issue?

I am using Enthought Canopy with Python 2.7 on a Windows 10 computer, if this is important.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `savefig()` after `show()` method?

Comment: @AhmetTavli No, I comment out show when I use savefig. I know that fig closes after show is used.

Comment: "using python for several years now and it was never this slow." What has changed? When was the last time that you saved to a PDF and it was *not* slow? Have you updated packages? Does it help to temporarily disable your AV software? What happens when you try with Python 3?

Comment: @JonathanMarch I am pretty sure something is wrong with my computer, so that was the main reason for me asking this question. I did savefig to pdf six months ago and I never noticed it being slow. I updated packages. Some other question pointed to pillow package so I checked if it is uptodate personally. I also disabled the AV but it was running okay with the same AV before. I reset canopy settings as well.

Comment: To be clear, updating packages is not always a solution -- unfortunately depending on the package and the computer, it might cause a problem like this! Tangentially, I would encourage you to move to Python 3 when you can, and also from Canopy to EDM. See https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038600051-Canopy-GUI-end-of-life-transition-to-the-Enthought-Deployment-Manager-EDM-and-Visual-Studio-Code